# How to add new partitions automatically in partitioned table based on data inserted in GreenPlum.?

Tags: greenplum

I have a partitioned table in greenplum(modeled after psql), which has been partitioned with specific range of values.

Now, i have to insert the data again into the same table. New values for Partitions might overlap with existing ones. I have created alter command with new start and end dates. But, if the overlaps are there, the command fails. So, i need to create partition for each date, in order to avoid whole command failure.

Just wondering, if there is a way in greenplum to create partitions based on the inserted data automatically, just like hive does.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Greenplum does not (currently) create additional partitions for data which does not fit into an existing partition.

If you have a default partition on the table it will receive all the records which do not fit into one of the specified partitions. You can then use `ALTER TABLE ... SPLIT DEFAULT PARTITION` (see [the documentation](http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4320/ref_guide/sql_commands/ALTER_TABLE.html) if required) to create the new partitions for any new dates at the end of the load batch.